# How to display items on the page depending on the value of the field? Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I generate fields with loadFields(). All of them are successfully rendered in html in a row. But I need fields to be rendered separately depending on the group. To be able to group them and add a header. I tried doing it with *ngIf="item.group === 'group1'" but it doesn't work.

I was able to exclude a field before with *ngIf="item.key !== 'item1'"

```js
loadFields() {
  this.fields = {
    item1: {
      group: 'group1',
      title: '',
      type: 'text',
      value: 'some value1',
      validation: [Validators.required]
    },
    item2: {
      group: 'group1',
      title: '',
      type: 'text',
      value: 'some value2',
      validation: [Validators.required]
    },
    item3: {
      group: 'group2',
      title: '',
      type: 'text',
      value: 'some value3',
      validation: [Validators.required]
    },
    item4: {
      group: 'group2',
      title: '',
      type: 'text',
      value: 'some value4',
      validation: [Validators.required]
    },
  }
}

originalOrder = (a: KeyValue<number, string>, b: KeyValue<number, string>): number => {
 return 0;
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of fields | keyvalue: originalOrder">

    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <legend class="h6">Group 1</legend>
      <div class="col-lg-12" *ngIf="item.group === 'group1'">
        <app-input-item
          [complexForm]="langComplexForm"
          [field]="item.value"
        ></app-input-item>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <legend class="h6">Group 2</legend>
      <div class="col-lg-12" *ngIf="item.group === 'group2'">
        <app-input-item
          [complexForm]="langComplexForm"
          [field]="item.value"
        ></app-input-item>
      </div>
    </div>

</ng-container>
```

Comment: Is this the actual code..? Anyway - you're using the keyvalue pipe it seems... so I would expect your values to look like item.value.group instead of item.group

Comment: Sorry, added value to the example. Here is just part of the code. I tried not to include unnecessary things here.

Answer (score 2):

you can use ngSwitch
https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch
something like this:

```
<ng-container 
  *ngFor="let item of fields | keyvalue: originalOrder"  
  >
<div [ngSwitch]="item.group"> 
  <div class="col-lg-12"  *ngSwitchCase="'group1'">
    <legend class="h6">Group 1</legend>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <app-input-item
        [complexForm]="langComplexForm"
        [field]="item.value"
      ></app-input-item>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12"  *ngSwitchCase="'group2'">
    <legend class="h6">Group 2</legend>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <app-input-item
        [complexForm]="langComplexForm"
        [field]="item.value"
      ></app-input-item>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Can Geylan, That's better. Two fields are rendered, but they are empty. Unfortunately, this method doesn't work for me now

Comment: It’s hard to test this without a running code example but I’m sure you can adjust it to your situation. This was just as an example.